# Can an associate editor of a journal see my name?

Tags: journals, editors, anonymity

Recently I received a rejection from a top journal. But when the editor in chief sent me the rejection email, she included the name of the associate editor that handled my paper. This associate editor works in a department which has a job opening this year that I have applied. So I'm nervous because if the associate editor can see my name, he could think negatively of me because of my paper, which could affect my chance to get the job. So can the associate editor see the author's name on their paper? Thank you!

Comment: Some things are unclear to me: Did the editor in chief put the associate editor in cc? If so then the answer to "can they see…" is obviously *yes*. But probably you wanted ask *should they see…* or *are the associate editors allowed to…*, but the answer to this is also *yes*.

Comment: What does it change now? You already applied for the job, and you already submitted your work.

Comment: If the paper review was not double-blind, then pretty much certainly. If the journal uses double-blind review, then maybe, maybe not,

Comment: @xLeitix Can you please post your answer as an answer?

Comment: @Dirk No I didn't want to ask should they see. My question is clear. Can he see. No she didn't cc him on the email

Comment: @xLeitix As you can see, I have not included an answer in my question.

Comment: @rr5832 If you are looking for sympathy, that's probably not the right place. The question in itself is pretty vague (unknown journal, unknown field, is the associate editor a reviewer, etc), and there is much certainly a bigger picture about it. Just trying to get what it is about. If it's just about being reassured... well, I'm not sure we can really help you with this. If you're wondering what to do about it, that is a different question that might need a bit more information.

Comment: Note that even if the editor can see your name (and they probably can), this is not necessarily a bad thing for your job prospects.  Now you know that somebody at the institution is familiar with your work.  And although they rejected your paper, they might still consider it to be good quality work, just not quite outstanding enough for the top journal.  That would still give you a  significant advantage over a random applicant who nobody in the department has ever heard of.

Answer (score 2):

With most journals, (handling) editors get to know who the authors of a paper are so they can avoid conflicts of interest when picking reviewers and similar.

A review process that avoids this is called ***triple-blind review***[¹](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-56549-1_17)[²](https://orgtheory.wordpress.com/2007/01/23/a-modest-proposal-triple-blind-review/)[³](https://hub.wiley.com/community/exchanges/discover/blog/2015/09/22/exploring-the-peer-review-process)[⁴](https://sciencematters.io/editorial-policies)[⁵](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201507/double-blind.cfm). As this is considered a selling point, I would consider it very unlikely that a journal does this without telling you about it on their website.